# How can I print SQL query with spring boot?

Tags: spring-boot, mybatis

I'm using Spring-boot 1.3.5.RELEASE, mybatis.spring.boot 1.1.1, MySQL  My Spring yml configuration is below

```
logging:
level: 
  com.ibatis: ERROR
  com.ibatis.common.jdbc.SimpleDataSource: DEBUG
  com.ibatis.common.jdbc.ScriptRunner: DEBUG
  com.ibatis.sqlmap.engine.impl.SqlMapClientDelegate: DEBUG
  java.sql: DEBUG
  java.sql.Connection: DEBUG
  java.sql.Statement: DEBUG
  java.sql.PreparedStatement: DEBUG
  java.sql.ResultSet: DEBUG
```

But it not work, please how can I print SQL query with spring boot?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a log lib like `log4j`, and properties must include following configuration:

```
log4j.logger.java.sql.ResultSet=TRACE
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how you get the logs:

```
<Logger name="com.dao.YourMyBatisMapperDao" level="all" additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="proj" />
</Logger>
<Logger name="com.ibatis.sqlmaps" level="all" additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="proj" />
</Logger>
<Logger name="import java.sql.Statement" level="all" additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="proj" />
</Logger>
<Logger name="import java.sql.PreparedStatement" level="all" additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="proj" />
</Logger>
```

You just need to change the above to your spring yaml format.